# How do I check if a variable value, set periodically by a timer, changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    var myRequest = $.ajax({ 
        //ask php to count rows from mysql table
        //data gets loaded with integer value
    });

    myRequest.done(function(data){ 
        var rowcount = JSON.stringify(data.data[0]).replace(/\"/g, ""); //integer value
    });

}, 5000);
```

So basically, count rows from a MySql table every 5 seconds.

My question is, when a new row has been added to to table, `rowcount` will change (e.g. +1). How do I make jQuery know that there is a change?

Comment: You simply store the old value in a higher scoped variable (i.e. declare `rowcount` outside of your timer function) and then in your `done` function, compare the new value with the old value. If they are different, go perform some action.

Comment: execute code when you detect it changed? I hope your server can handle all those calls.

Comment: Please precise what you mean by `How do I make jQuery know that there is a change?` and explain the *why* underneath it

Answer (score 0):

keep track of the last rowcount and compare it, as mentioned in Scott's comment:

```js
let rowcount = 0;
function onRowcountChange() {
  // do something spiffy here
}

setInterval(function() { 
    var myRequest = $.ajax({ 
        //ask php to count rows from mysql table
        //data gets loaded with integer value
    });

    myRequest.done(function(data){ 
        var newrows = JSON.stringify(data.data[0]).replace(/\"/g, ""); //integer value
        if(newrows !== rowcount) { // if the value changed
            onRowcountChange(); // do your update code
            rowcount = newrows; // set rowcount to new value
        }
    });

}, 5000);
```